# How to register Handlebars Intl helper in NestJs mailer

Tags: handlebars.js, nestjs

I need to implement some format for my data in @nest-modules/mailer but the best I got is an error: "formatNumber" not defined in...

As I found in the formatjs.io/handlebars I try to register the helper to my Handlebars

where

```
import { HandlebarsAdapter, MailerModule } from '@nest-modules/mailer';
import { HandlebarsIntl } from 'handlebars-intl';
```

I try

```
const adapter = new HandlebarsAdapter();
HandlebarsIntl.registerWith(adapter);
```

but I get registerWith is not a funcion
and

```
MailerModule.forRoot({
  transport,
  defaults: {
    from: '"nest-modules" <_testaccount@sample.com>',
  },
  template: {
    dir: './templates',
    adapter: new HandlebarsAdapter(),
    options: {
      strict: true,
      helpers: HandlebarsIntl,
    },
  },
}),
```

this compile but throw "formatNumber" not defined in...

Answer (score 1):

You can register your helper function by providing it to handlebar adapter like so:

```js
const upperCaseFn = (name: string) => {
    return name.toUpperCase();
}

@Module({
  imports: [
    MailerModule.forRoot({
      transport,
      defaults,
      template: {
        dir: './templates',
        adapter: new HandlebarsAdapter({'helper_name': upperCaseFn}), // <-- Here
      },
    })
  ]
})
export class MailModule {}
```

and then you can use it in your handlebar template like so:

```html
<p>{{helper_name name}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
import { MailerModule } from '@nestjs-modules/mailer';
import { HandlebarsAdapter } from '@nestjs-modules/mailer/dist/adapters/handlebars.adapter';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import * as handlebarsHelpers from 'handlebars-helpers';

@Module({
    imports: [
        MailerModule.forRootAsync({
            imports   : [ConfigModule],
            inject    : [ConfigService],
            useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
                transport: {
                    host     : configService.get<string>('MAILER_HOST'),
                    port     : +configService.get<number>('MAILER_PORT'),
                    ignoreTLS: configService.get<string>('MAILER_IGNORE_TLS') === 'true' ? true : false,
                    secure   : configService.get<string>('MAILER_SECURE') === 'true' ? true : false,
                    auth     : {
                        user: configService.get<string>('MAILER_USER'),
                        pass: configService.get<string>('MAILER_PASSWORD'),
                    },
                },
                defaults: {
                    from: configService.get<string>('MAILER_FROM'),
                },
                template: {
                    dir    : __dirname + '/templates',
                    adapter: new HandlebarsAdapter({ ...handlebarsHelpers() }),
                    options: {
                        strict: true,
                    },
                },
            }),
        }),
    ],
})
export class MailerCLientModule { }
```

Remenber import module in your **app.module.ts**

Answer (score -1):

This works. Register both your own customer helpers and 'handlebars-helpers':

```
const hbshelpers = require('handlebars-helpers');
const multihelpers = hbshelpers();

const helpersDM = {
    hlp: echo => `Echo: ${echo}.`,
    STATIC: `/static`,
};
const hbs = exphbs.create({
    layoutsDir: join(__dirname, 'views', 'layouts'),
    partialsDir: join(__dirname, 'views', 'partials'),
    extname: '.hbs',
    defaultLayout: 'base',
    helpers: {...multihelpers, ...helpersDM},
});
app.engine('.hbs', hbs.engine);
app.setViewEngine('.hbs');
```